# Embeding matplotlib graph in pyqt5 widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm trying to embed a matplotlib plot in pyqt5 widget, i tried some of the methodes but i can't get it done. i'm new to pyqt5 and i don't understand how to embed mapltplotlib plot in a Qtwidget.

Here is my qt designer generated python file,

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '.\ui\main_window_new.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1221, 583)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.top = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.top.setStyleSheet("")
        self.top.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.top.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.top.setObjectName("top")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.top)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.top)
        self.frame_3.setStyleSheet("")
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_3)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("margin-bottom:10px;")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 0))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label)
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.spinBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.spinBox.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(1)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(31)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 0))
        self.label_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.spinBox_2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.spinBox_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.spinBox_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 30))
        self.spinBox_2.setMinimum(1)
        self.spinBox_2.setMaximum(12)
        self.spinBox_2.setObjectName("spinBox_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.spinBox_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.frame_5 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_3)
        self.frame_5.setStyleSheet("")
        self.frame_5.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_5.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_5.setObjectName("frame_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_5)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_5)
        self.label_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 0))
        self.label_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.frame_5)
        self.comboBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 30))
        self.comboBox.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 30))
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_5)
        self.label_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 0))
        self.label_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("margin-left:5px;")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.frame_5)
        self.comboBox_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 30))
        self.comboBox_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 30))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.comboBox_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_5, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_3, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.frame_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.top)
        self.frame_4.setStyleSheet("padding:0 15px;")
        self.frame_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_4.setObjectName("frame_4")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_4)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.frame_6 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_4)
        self.frame_6.setStyleSheet("margin-bottom:10px;")
        self.frame_6.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_6.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_6.setObjectName("frame_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_6)
        self.label_5.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 0))
        self.label_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame_6)
        self.lineEdit_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 30))
        self.lineEdit_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 30))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_6)
        self.label_6.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 0))
        self.label_6.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_6)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame_6)
        self.lineEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 30))
        self.lineEdit.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 30))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_6, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.frame_7 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_4)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.frame_7.setFont(font)
        self.frame_7.setStyleSheet("")
        self.frame_7.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_7.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_7.setObjectName("frame_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_7)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_7)
        self.label_7.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 0))
        self.label_7.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.spinBox_4 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.frame_7)
        self.spinBox_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 30))
        self.spinBox_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 30))
        self.spinBox_4.setStyleSheet("padding:0;")
        self.spinBox_4.setMinimum(1)
        self.spinBox_4.setMaximum(12)
        self.spinBox_4.setObjectName("spinBox_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.spinBox_4)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_7)
        self.label_8.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 0))
        self.label_8.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.spinBox_3 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.frame_7)
        self.spinBox_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 30))
        self.spinBox_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 30))
        self.spinBox_3.setStyleSheet("padding:0;")
        self.spinBox_3.setMinimum(1)
        self.spinBox_3.setMaximum(12)
        self.spinBox_3.setObjectName("spinBox_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.spinBox_3)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_7)
        self.label_9.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 0))
        self.label_9.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_9)
        self.comboBox_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.frame_7)
        self.comboBox_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 30))
        self.comboBox_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 16777215))
        self.comboBox_3.setStyleSheet("padding:0;")
        self.comboBox_3.setObjectName("comboBox_3")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.comboBox_3)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_7, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_4, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.top)
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(83, 83, 83);")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.contour = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_2)
        self.contour.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.contour.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.contour.setObjectName("contour")
        self.horizontalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.contour)
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_8")
        self.widget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.contour)
        self.widget_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(420, 320))
        self.widget_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(420, 320))
        self.widget_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 255, 0);")
        self.widget_2.setObjectName("widget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.widget_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.contour)
        self.xy = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_2)
        self.xy.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.xy.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.xy.setObjectName("xy")
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.xy)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.xy)
        self.widget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(420, 320))
        self.widget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(420, 320))
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 170, 255);")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.xy)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1221, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuInitialize = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuInitialize.setObjectName("menuInitialize")
        self.menuSettings = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuSettings.setObjectName("menuSettings")
        self.menuUpdate = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuUpdate.setObjectName("menuUpdate")
        self.menuHelp = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName("menuHelp")
        self.menuAbout = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuAbout.setObjectName("menuAbout")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName("toolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)
        self.actionSave = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/icons/285657_floppy_guardar_save_icon.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionSave.setIcon(icon)
        self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")
        self.actionnew = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/icons/1904677_add_addition_calculate_charge_create_icon.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionnew.setIcon(icon1)
        self.actionnew.setObjectName("actionnew")
        self.actionreset = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/icons/8111405_reset_reload_refresh_sync_arrow_icon.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionreset.setIcon(icon2)
        self.actionreset.setObjectName("actionreset")
        self.actionupdate = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/icons/3298600_new_blank_document_folder_icon.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionupdate.setIcon(icon3)
        self.actionupdate.setObjectName("actionupdate")
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuInitialize.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuSettings.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuUpdate.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAbout.menuAction())
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionnew)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionSave)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionreset)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionupdate)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Day"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Month"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Parameters"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Temperature"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "rh"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "uwind"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "vwind"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Pressure"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "20"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "40"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "60"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "80"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Latitude"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Longitude"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Day"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Month"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Parameters"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Temperature"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "rh"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "uwind"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "vwind"))
        self.menuInitialize.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Initialize"))
        self.menuSettings.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Settings"))
        self.menuUpdate.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Update"))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help"))
        self.menuAbout.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "About"))
        self.toolBar.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "toolBar"))
        self.actionSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.actionSave.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.actionnew.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "new"))
        self.actionnew.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "New"))
        self.actionreset.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "reset"))
        self.actionreset.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Reset"))
        self.actionupdate.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "update"))
        self.actionupdate.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Update"))
import resource_rc
```

here is my main file

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from main_ui import *

class MainWIndow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWIndow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is my code for ploting graph

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def show():
    x = [1, 2, 3]
    y = [2, 4, 1]
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.xlabel('x - axis')
    plt.ylabel('y - axis')
    plt.title('test')
    plt.show()

show()
```

this is how my ui looks like

[image: Image of ui]

and i want to plot the matplotlib plot in blue window

How to emebed the plot correctly in the QtWidget? it will be really helpful if some one explain how to do it

Comment: Did you try this tutorial:  https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/plotting-matplotlib/ ? Or this one https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-embed-matplotlib-graph-in-pyqt5/

Comment: @Demi-Lune Hi, I Saw that but when i tried that i can't find how to make that to my requirements like i want to plot in the place of blue color widget but i can't do i completly new to pyqt5.